# What's the difference between BITMAP and COMPACT indexing in hive?

Tags: hive

I know that indexing has been removed in the latest versions of hive, but I'd still like to know the difference between the 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is how they store the mapping from values to the rows in which the value occurs so that when we query we can identify the blocks fast which has relevant data.

**Compact indexing** stores the pair of indexed column’s value and its block id while **Bitmap indexing** stores the combination of indexed column value and list of rows as a bitmap.

**Bitmap indexing** is a standard technique for indexing columns with few distinct values.

I would recommend to read this excellent blog post about [Hive Indexing](https://acadgild.com/blog/indexing-in-hive).

**Additional Information**

There are other things which you might want to know here.

Indexes has been removed with Hive 3.0, they recommend to use materialized view to achieve similar results but I would say go with columnar storage like `PARQUET` or `ORC`, they they can do selective scanning and even skip entire files/blocks.

`ORC` format has build in Indexes which allow the format to skip blocks of data during read, they also support Bloom filters index.